# Can "Pillars of Eternity" be finished on Nintendo Switch?

Tags: nintendo-switch, pillars-of-eternity

*Pillars of Eternity* is famously [broken](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/270124-pillars-of-eternity-complete-edition/79359485) on Nintendo Switch, with the developers having [refused to patch it](https://www.nintendolife.com/news/2021/02/pillars_of_eternity_will_get_no_more_patches_on_switch_despite_unresolved_issues). I'm wondering if it's possible to finish the main game and the two-part expansion pack, even with all the bugs. Has anyone managed to beat the whole thing, or the bugs are so bad that make this unfeasible on a Switch?